# Long to int conversion in Java gives incorrect result

Tags: java, type-conversion, primitive-types

I am trying seperate out the digits of a long number so that it can be represented as array of integers
e.g.

```
12345......888     as [1,2,3,4,......8,8,8]
```

In usual way I am taking n%10 to take out last digit and n/10 to reduce the number i.e.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long temp = 111111111111111110L;
    while(temp>0){
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println(temp%10);
        System.out.println((int)temp%10);
        temp=temp/10;
    }
}
```

temp%10 gives correct result. But it cannot be directly added to list of int. If I try to type cast it gives incorrect results for first few iterations.
Output

```
----------
0
-2
----------
1
9
----------
1
-5
----------
1
1
----------
1
9
----------
1
-3
----------
1
-5
----------
1
-7
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
----------
1
1
```

The workaround I used is

```
int digitArray[] = new int[somenumber];
String s = Long.toString(n);
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    digitArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(i));
}
```

But I am curious why type casting is not working in first way when the number being type-casted is single digit i.e. well within range of long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expression evaluation rules lead to this problem.

when you did

```
(int)temp%10
```

Actually the big `long` value  `temp` being casted to `int` which leads to `integer` overflow ,

you meant

```
(int)(temp%10)
```

Comment: Thanks. So foolish I am! Such a silly thing; ashamed of myself that I did this mistake at first place and I was not able even figure it out .